# Hive Flutter, How to get values in reverse key order

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a library called Hive which is a very fast NoSQL database. I have everything set up and I am trying to get the values in reverse order (Last in First Out).

I have a box of entries, each entry has a creation date and an entry text. As you can see in the code that whenever an entry is created the date of it is "Now". I want to get the list of entries **starting from the most recent entry (latest date)**. by default, the first entry added using `box.add()` will have a key of 0, the one after it is 1, and etc. In Hive's documentation, it says that fetching the values can be done "in reverse lexicographic order" but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part '../type_adapters/entry.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Entry extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String _entryText;
  @HiveField(1)
  DateTime _creationDate;
  Entry(this._entryText) {
    _creationDate = DateTime.now();
  }

  String get entryText => _entryText;
  DateTime get creationDate => _creationDate;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "$_entryText, $_creationDate, $key";
  }
}
```

library link:
[Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) [Hive Documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/)

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out, you have to pass your own sorting function when **opening the box**. the *default* way that Hive does is:

```
/// Efficient default implementation to compare keys
int defaultKeyComparator(dynamic k1, dynamic k2) {
  if (k1 is int) {
    if (k2 is int) {
      if (k1 > k2) {
        return 1;
      } else if (k1 < k2) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  } else if (k2 is String) {
    return (k1 as String).compareTo(k2);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

their default function gets you values in lexicographic order. **in order to reverse it**, had to pass my own "keyComparator" (which is the function used to sort the values, it receives 2 keys and returns an int)

so when opening the box:

```
_entryBox = await Hive.openBox(ENTRY_BOX, keyComparator: _reverseOrder);
```

_reverseOrder function:

```
  int _reverseOrder(k1, k2) {
    if (k1 is int) {
      if (k2 is int) {
        if (k1 > k2) {
          return -1;
        } else if (k1 < k2) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }
```

it gets a bit more complicated if you want to use start and end keys instead of getting all the values at once (  `box.valuesBetween(startKey: , endKey:,` ).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's pretty late to add an answer to this threat. But I'm adding it if anyone else got stuck on this.

Hive doesn't support sorting.
So the **easiest way** is to sort the list after getting the values out of the box.

```
entryList = entryBox.values;
```

Now sort the list before showing it on the UI.

```
entryList.sort((a, b) => -a._creationDate.compareTo(b._creationDate));
```

*The (-) sign reverses the list from the most recent timestamp to the older one.*

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution that I've found effective:

First, open a storage box using Hive with the following command:

```dart
box = await Hive.openBox('hive_box');
```

Then, to get the items stored in the box in reverse order, use this:

```dart
var items = box.values.toList().reversed.toList();
```